# My smtp password contains special character giving error

Tags: javascript, meteor, smtp

I'm working on Meteor to send emails

In my main.js file I put my smtp password that contain (%) something like "i%au"

Eg

```
Meteor.statup(() => {
process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://abc%40gmail.com:i%au@smtp.gmail.com:587"
})
```

I get the below error

> URIError: URI malformed at decodeURIComponent

I know that by removing % from the password will make it work, but can someone please explain me if there is any alternative solution to this problem i.e. If I want to include % in the password

Comment: Your `%` must be encoded as `%25`

Comment: The problem is exactly what `decodeURIComponent` is saying it is: A malformed URI. The sequence `%au` is not valid. (There's also no need to encode `@`.) `%` is reserved in `%`-encoding. You can use `%25` if you need to have a `%` in the URI. (Or better yet, don't handcode things. Use `encodeURI` to get the valid string: `"mailto://abc@gmail.com:i%25au@smtp.gmail.com:587"`)